# typescript compiler giving error redeclare block-scoped variable but it is not redeclared

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I just get started with typescript. after creation this line of code `const name: string = 'test'` then eslint is yelling at me that

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.ts(2451)
> lib.dom.d.ts(18092, 15): 'name' was also declared here.

and after cmpilation with tsc I got this error  :

> src/app.ts:4:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.
>
> 4 const name: string = 'test'
> ~~~~
>
> C:/Users/******/******/*******/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:18092:15
> 18092 declare const name: void;
> ~~~~
> 'name' was also declared here.

checking this file **lib.dom.d.ts** it seems there is already a variable named
`name`  . so it seems that tsc is compiling even the files in node modules not just my files

what am I missing ?

I have checked my tsconfig.json file but it seems okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems , I am using a variable **`name`** that clashes with TypeScript global typings. because it is already declared  in the `lib.dom.d.ts`.

converting the file to an ES module solved the issue  :

```
const name = 'test'
export {} // add this to  mark the file as an external module
```